# Latest Laravel and latest WAMP issues

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have them both vanilla setup. Laravel setups up fine. But when i run composer install i get;

```
>   Problem 1
     - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.   
Problem 2
     - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.   
Problem 3

....
 Problem 24
    - Installation request for sebastian/diff 3.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[3.0.1].
    - sebastian/diff 3.0.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 25
    - laravel/framework v5.6.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/tinker v1.0.7 requires illuminate/console ~5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.26].
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker v1.0.7 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v1.0.7].
```

A total of 25 problems when running composer on laravel...
I have understood so much my php version differs in minor version, but what can i do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You have PHP version 7.0, packages installed by composer require PHP 7.1 - so you need to update your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

I think your laravel version wants php version >= 7.1.3 but your installed  version is 7.0.11.
If you have installed latest laravel version i.e(5.6) then it should match following requirements:

```
PHP >= 7.1.3
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
Ctype PHP Extension
JSON PHP Extension
```

Please check laravel installation guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#installation

Answer (score 0):

Yea, there where mismatches in version. Strangley enough i downloaded another phpversion 7.2.xx. And it almost worked like a charm. They have some strange things going on eg. the extensions config directive s never prefixed with "php_" in the ini file and it is very easy to miss, so you will need to add it yourswelf also there are no extension dir config by default, you also need that one. Its commented out, another workhour to find this this.

Thanks for your reply!